# Move div to left on click and back to regular position on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, onclick, jquery-animate

I have a navigation menu with a drop down on click and once the "resources" link is clicked I would like to have it moved to the left in the middle of the container div then once the viewer moves the mouse out of the resources link it goes back to it's regular position.

I tried to add these lines to my mini script//

```
jQuery( "#RXCLICK" ).animate({
    left: "+=50"
});
```

but nothing happens.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U9uN2/1/).

My question is,
Why exactly doesn't the animation work?
What am I doing wrong?
Please help.

Comment: I don't see any elements in your example that have an ID of RXCLICK

Comment: @akousmata Correct, I used # instead of a period, totally forgot I used class instead of ID, I switched the # for a period and now the animation works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you want to animate the round ball instead of the menu?

You either really meant:

```
// You used a pound to refer to an ID instead of a class...
jQuery( ".RXCLICK" ).animate({
  left: "+=50"
});
```

Or,

```
// This would move the menu, not the round ball.
jQuery( ".RXMENU" ).animate({
  left: "+=50"
});
```

Comment: I will accept your answer since it makes the ball move. But a new error occurred, should I update my question or post a new question?

Comment: You should google around for that new error, make a dedicated search and attempt by yourself to fix the error, and then if unsuccessful, post a new question. That's how stack overflow works.